# Can I add my own UDF as an inbuilt function to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have developed a function `myfunction`. Can I make it a PostgreSQL built-in function like the `count` or `max` functions?

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL is an open-source community.You can contribute if you wish to. Please go through  [this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/So,_you_want_to_be_a_developer%3F) to know how

Comment: Once you created a function using `create function` you can use it just like any other (built-in) function. When looking a SQL statement that uses it, you can't tell the difference

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- If you think that your function should be a part of core PostgreSQL, because it is useful to many users, get in touch with the pgsql-hackers mailing list. The [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/So,_you_want_to_be_a_developer%3F) provided by Kaushik Nayak above is good reading.

  Discuss the idea and design before posting a patch - odds are good that it will have to be rewritten. You'll have to attract reviewers and a committer to get your patch in. You need patience and persistence.
- You can keep your patch outside of PostgreSQL and adapt it to new versions as they come out. That is tedious.
- Because yours is a frequent demand, and core cannot (and doesn't want to) include everything, PostgreSQL is very extensible. It is easy to package your function as an extension. This makes maintenance and installation so much easier, because you don't have to rebuild PostgreSQL.

  You can publish your extension. Just because it isn't in core doesn't mean that it has to be unpopular. Think of PostGIS that for many people is a reason to get involved with PostgreSQL in the first place.

Comment: Instead of giving a query like "select myfunction(table name)", is it possible to query like " select myfunction() from tablename"?

Comment: The first form you quote will require *dynamic SQL*, which is cumbersome and prone to SQL injection, so avoid it if possible. The second form is possible, but not what you want. Usually, you would write statements like `SELECT myfunc(col1, 2 * col2) FROM atable`.